# Hive - Group by datetime column to date only

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, group-by, presto, amazon-athena

In my table eventtime column looks like,

```
2017-03-25T03:18:00001Z
2017-03-25T05:21:00013Z
```

I want to group by eventtime with date only.

Like

```
2017-03-18, 2017-03-21
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Ya, I tried many commands,date_format(from_iso8601_timestamp(eventTime), '%Y-%m-%d')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it both in the `GROUP BY` and the `SELECT` clauses.

```
cast (from_iso8601_timestamp(eventtime) as date)
```

Comment: Ok Dude, let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP BY CAST(myDateTime AS DATE)
```

Comment: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:12: '"eventtime"' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause